# Why do I have to click two times to open the <Modal /> when I return from a page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, simplemodal, onpress, react-native-modal

I made a button type to open the modal on the Home page, the modal is coming fine and closing fine when click on the overlay, the problem is when I got some page with the list inside`<Modal />` component and when I come back to the Home page and then if I click on that button to open the  it doesn't open on first click yet. I have to click two times to open it. What is the issue here? I can't understand.

Here is my code:

```js
//Home.js
const modalData = [
  { key: "Add Dealer", navigateTo: "AddDealer" },
  { key: "Add Franchise", navigateTo: "AddFranchise" },
  { key: "New Lead", navigateTo: "AddNewLeads" },
];

export default function Home() {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const renderPopList = ({ item, index }) => {
    const lastItem = index === modalData.length - 1;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.navigateTo)}>
        <Text style={[styles.links, lastItem && styles.lastLink]}>
          {item.key}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={toggleModal}
        onTouchStart={toggleModal}
        style={styles.modalWrapper}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={toggleModal}>
          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" }}
            onPress={toggleModal}
          ></View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <FlatList
          data={modalData}
          renderItem={renderPopList}
          onPress={toggleModal}
          style={[styles.modal]}
        />
      </Modal>
      //Button Here
      <View style={styles.bottomBtnWrap}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addBtn} onPress={toggleModal}>
          <FontAwesome color="#fff" name="plus" size={30} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Probably due to the nature of toggling where some state might not update correctly, especially with the toggleModal-function being passed multiple places inside a nesting which can lead to multiple toggles with one click. Instead you can explicitly state an open and a close-function and use those on the button and modal respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for it

```
//Home.js
const modalData = [
  { key: "Add Dealer", navigateTo: "AddDealer" },
  { key: "Add Franchise", navigateTo: "AddFranchise" },
  { key: "New Lead", navigateTo: "AddNewLeads" },
];

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("blur", () => {
      setModalVisible(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  const renderPopList = ({ item, index }) => {
    const lastItem = index === modalData.length - 1;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.navigateTo)}>
        <Text style={[styles.links, lastItem && styles.lastLink]}>
          {item.key}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={toggleModal}
      onTouchStart={toggleModal}
      style={styles.modalWrapper}
    >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={toggleModal}>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" }}
          onPress={toggleModal}
        ></View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <FlatList
        data={modalData}
        renderItem={renderPopList}
        onPress={toggleModal}
        style={[styles.modal]}
      />
    </Modal>
    //Button Here
    <View style={styles.bottomBtnWrap}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addBtn} onPress={toggleModal}>
        <FontAwesome color="#fff" name="plus" size={30} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```